# hide div if it contains no text

Tags: jquery

If `PageHeaderDescription` contains no text content then I want to hide it. Is it possible with jquery?

```
<div class="PageHeaderDescription">
  <h1>Accessories</h1>
  <img border="0" src="" style="cursor: pointer; display: none;" id="EntityPic621">
</div>
```

This is what the div looks like with text:

```
<div class="PageHeaderDescription">
  <h1>Accessories</h1>
  <img border="0" src="" style="cursor: pointer; display: none;" id="EntityPic621">
  This is the Accessories page, you can find stuff for the products!
</div>
```

Comment: You should probably wrap the text in a `<span></span>` or something, then you could check it whit `$('theSpanSelector').is(':empty');`

Comment: i cant wrap the text because its done in the CMS by the customer on 180 products. Its too much hassle X 180 different websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets hacky because I have to go a little deeper in the DOM than I'd like, but works for what you're going for:

```
$('div.PageHeaderDescription').each(function(i,e){
    var txt = '';
    for (var c = 0; c < e.childNodes.length; c++){
        if (e.childNodes[c].nodeType===3){
            txt += e.childNodes[c].data;
        }
    }
    if (txt.trim().length===0){
        $(e).hide();
    }
});
```

Again, hacky but effective. You have to keep in mind that even whitespace is accounted for in the DOM so it's not enough to check/filter by "there are no nodeType===3 elements". Instead, you concatenate all text, then trim it to remove whitespace and get the length.

---

Follow-up with a custom selector:

```
(function($){
    $.expr[':'].notext = function(obj, index, meta, stack){
        var txt = '';
        for (var c = 0; c < obj.childNodes.length; c++){
            if (obj.childNodes[c].nodeType===3){
                txt += obj.childNodes[c].data;
            }
        }
        return (txt.trim().length===0);
    };
})(jQuery);

$('div.PageHeaderDescription:notext').hide();
```

And of course the [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3RpqE/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("PageHeaderDescription").each(function(i, val) {
    if ($(this).text().trim() === "") {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: I believe `.text()` is still going to grab the `<h1>` text, no?

Comment: I presume you meant `$(".PageHeaderDescription")`.

Answer (score 1):

```
​jQuery(document).ready(function(){

   // alert(jQuery('.PageHeaderDescription').text());

    var headerTxt = jQuery('.PageHeaderDescription h1').text();
    //alert(headerTxt);    

        if(jQuery.trim(jQuery('.PageHeaderDescription').text())==headerTxt ){
        jQuery('.PageHeaderDescription').hide();
    } 


});​
```

Comment: and what happens when my page says products? this is not managable with 180+ pages x 180 sites.

Comment: @Super1 modified my answer to handle the case

Comment: Just comparing what is inside the H1 with the entire text to see that there is no other text in the div.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
if( $('div.PageHeaderDescription').is(':empty') ) {
    // Your code
}
```

Comment: Once again, `:empty` won't work in the case as it's determinant on child elements not just text.

Answer (score 1):

You will need another function to grab only the text inside the div that aren't within some tags. When you use .text() straight in `PageHeaderDescription` you will got the h1's inner text too. More information about `.justText()` you can see [HERE!](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-get-text-element-without-child-element/)

The answer is:

```
jQuery.fn.justText = function() {
  return $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text();
};

$('document').ready(function(){
    if ($('.PageHeaderDescription').justText().trim().length == 0) {
      $('.PageHeaderDescription').remove(); // If you want to hide, use .hide()
    }
  }
);
```

*PS.: To help you to choose between .hide() and .remove()*

--[.hide()'s Reference](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

--[.remove()'s Reference](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#empty").click(function() {
      alert($('#myDiv').is(':empty'));
    });
```

or

```
$("div:empty").hide();
```

or'

you can use :is for checking

```
if( $('#leftmenu').is(':empty') ) {
}
```

Comment: `:empty` is only true when there are no child elements. In OP's case, child elements are irrelevant, it's just the text that matters (so `:empty` most likely won't work)

Answer (score 0):

First assign a id= to you Div.

```
<div class="PageHeaderDescription" id="PageHeaderDescription">
```

Then

```
$("#PageHeaderDescription").each(function(i, val) {
    if ($(this).text().trim() === "") {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
var clone = ​$(".PageHeaderDescription").clone(true);​​​​​​​​​
clone.find('*').remove();
if (clone.text().trim() == '') $(".PageHeaderDescription").hide();
clone.remove();
```